# Count number of async scripts in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, synchronization

I have a script `script.js` that calls in advertisements into the DOM. It is invserted after `#closeImage` if some test is true:

```
<div id="overlay">
    <img id="closeImage" src="close100x100.png">
</div>
```

If the test is true I call my script.

```
if (test) {
         var script = document.createElement('script');
         script.type = 'text/javascript';
         script.src = 'script.js';
         $("#closeImage").append(script);
```

`script.js` might not find an advertisement. In this case from within `script.js`,  `script01.js` which will be inserted into the DOM to look for different advertisements. If nothing is found `script03.js` will be called from within `script02.js` and so my `div` might end looking like this:

```
<div id="overlay">
    <img id="closeImage" src="close100x100.png">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="script01.js"></script>
    <script src="script02.js"></script>
    <!-- actual banner html -->
</div>
```

Only the first script is being inserted by the original `document.createElement()`. How do I count the number of scripts in `#overlay`? - This did not work:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  var loaded = $('div#ADF_overlay script').length;
});
```

**EDIT** (Restated the problem differently based on feedback)

Comment: Is your actual problem that you want to know how to execute some code AFTER all your dynamically inserted scripts are loaded?  Because counting script tags won't tell you whether those scripts have loaded or not.  FYI, `$(document).ready()` does not wait for dynamically inserted scripts to load and execute.  It fires when the content that was in the original HTML of the page has been downloaded and parsed (except it doesn't wait for images to load).

Comment: Also, do you realize that when you dynamically add script elements, it doesn't matter where in your content you insert them.  They are downloaded and run asycnhronously no matter where they are inserted.  Your use of `$("#closeImage").append(script);` makes it look like you think there's a reason to insert the scripts in a specific place when that is not the case.

Comment: These scripts are generating advertisment banners, so the location of running these scripts makes a difference as ultimately they will load image files.

Comment: did you try to use the F12 tools? You can see all the elements and see the DOM change as your scripts manipulate the DOM. Plus you can watch the network waterfall and see all the resources loaded etc.

Comment: F12 tools will not work here. I need to be able to determine it with javascript.

Comment: @jfriend00: Yes, my problem is that AFTER all dynamically inserted scripts are loaded/inserted into the DOM, I want to count how many of them there is.

Comment: When are you inserting the scripts (before or after `$(document).ready()` fires)?  And, when do you want to know how many have been inserted?  Do you actually need to know when all the scripts have finished loading and executing?  Or you just want to know how many have been inserted (inserted and loaded are two different things)?  Perhaps you can tell from my questions, but the timing of when you are doing what and when you want to know what is not clear at all from your question.  Perhaps you can show a sequence of events that shows when you want to know how many scripts there are.

Comment: FYI, you can't dynamically insert script elements that use `document.write()` to insert their ad content inline at the point of the script insertion.  If that's what you're trying to do, you will need a different approach.  First off, dynamically inserted scripts run asychronously (they aren't run as the content is parsed).  Second off, when a script uses `document.write()` on a document that is already loaded, the document is cleared and a new empty document is started.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for taking the time to answer so nicely. Right now i `document.createElement('script')` before `$(document).ready()` fires.

Comment: @jfriend00 Regarding the difference in loading and inserting. When I run `script.js` it will look for a banner ad to display. If nothing is found it will insert `script01.js`. And so on for `script02.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My main guess here is that you have a timing issue.  You are inserting a script, which has to load and then execute, which may then insert another script which has to load and then execute and you don't actually know when that process is done so you can check how many scripts were loaded in total.

`$(document).ready()` will not wait for that process to be done - it only waits for the original HTML of the document to be parsed (and any inline scripts that were there in the original HTML and don't have the defer or async attributes will run).

The only way to know when a cascade of dynamically loaded scripts are actually done is to have the last script somehow mark when it's done (either by calling a function, triggering an event, setting a variable or marking something in the DOM).  Without the script telling you when it's done inserting new script tags, you can't know whether the next script is still loading and waiting to run which might insert some more scripts, etc...

We could probably help better with ideas for solving your overall problem (what you are actually trying to accomplish) if you described the overall problem rather than just this one piece that you're trying to use.

---

If you just want to count how many dynamically insert scripts there are, then it would be simplest to just maintain a javascript counter as you insert them and then you can use that counter sometime later.

```
var scriptsInserted = 0;

if (seenOverlay('served') === 'false') {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'script.js';
        $("#closeImage").append(script);
        ++scriptsInserted;
}
```

Then, some time later, you can just refer to your variable `scriptsInserted` to access the count.

---

Alternatively, you can put a class name on your script elements and just query for that:

```
if (seenOverlay('served') === 'false') {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'script.js';
        script.className = "adScript";
        $("#closeImage").append(script);
        ++scriptsInserted;
}
```

And, some time later:

```
$(".adScript").length;
```

---

If you're dynamically inserting a cascade of scripts (insert one, which loads, runs and then inserts another, and so on), then when do you know to check to see how many scripts were actually inserted?  The timing of when to check may also be an issue for you because if you're checking that in `$(document).ready()`, then that process may not be done yet as each dynamically inserted script is loaded asynchronously and `$(document).ready()` can easily fire before that process is done because it doesn't wait for dynamically inserted scripts to load or run.

---

It appears that you may potentially have other issues because inserting a script into a particular place in an already loaded document will usually not insert content at that place in the document because a dynamically loaded script element can't use `document.write()` to insert content into the existing document in the same way that a normal inline `<script>` tag can.

Comment: This is a great idea BUT my own `document.createElement('script')` only creates the first script, so the counter will always be 0 or 1. The the inserted `script.js` will write the rest of the possible scripts itself.

Comment: @user1965074 - Then how can you ever know when all the script loading is done?

Comment: There will be at most three scripts. That is why I need to count this.  If I can count four scripts, I know that a banner has been served because the banner itself is one additional scripts. If it is less than or equal to three I know that no banner was served.

Comment: @user1965074 - Do you understand that you don't know when the ad scripts are done?  You might see two right now, but the second one is still loading and when it runs, it will insert a third or when you see two, they are all done and that's all you're going to see.  You don't know which of those two scenarios it is.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. If I implement the script as a `<script>` in within the `<body>` I can get away with `$(document).ready(function () { $('div#overlay script').length; });`

Comment: @user1965074 - Even that won't work if your script triggers dynamic loading of other scripts that they do more dynamic loading.  You may be getting lucky with timing, but there is NO guaranteed timing of dynamically loaded scripts and they have no relation at all to when `$(document).ready()` fires.

Comment: @user1965074 - And, if you don't even know how many script tags are going to be inserted, you really have no idea when they're done.  What you are attempting to do is just a bad design.  About all you could do is poll with a `setInterval()` and wait for some period of time (which is impossible to predict accurately) before it "appears" that it must be done adding more script tags.